# SQL toggle variable in database

Tags: sql, database, toggle, procedure

I have a procedure for a table in my database, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to. Could someone check if I am doing it wrong? I am new to SQL all together.

This is my procedure.
It is supposed to change admin status from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1 when I tell it to. But for some reason it changes it and doesn't change it back :(

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sesuser].[Login_Admin_Toggle]
(
    @loginID INT
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @tmpId INTEGER;

SET @tmpId = (SELECT SESAdmin FROM [ses_users].[sesuser].[SESLogin] WHERE SESLoginID = @loginID);

IF (@tmpId = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @tmpId = 0
    RETURN
END
ELSE
    SET @tmpId = 1

UPDATE [ses_users].[sesuser].[SESLogin]
SET SESAdmin = @tmpId   
WHERE SESLoginID = @loginID

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex K is completely right.  You set your variable to 0 then RETURN, meaning that you never get to the UPDATE statement from there.

But, on a slight tangent, you can actually do all of that in one statement...

```
BEGIN

  UPDATE [ses_users].[sesuser].[SESLogin]
  SET SESAdmin = 1 - SESAdmin
  WHERE SESLoginID = @loginID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't toggle back because you `RETURN` and so halt execution if `@tmpId = 1`, so its never updated to `0`.

Comment: I have seen the if statement written like so in an example, thus i assumed it was correct syntax. Could you advise how i should correctly write it?

Comment: Just remove the RETURN line.  RETURN is a command that means "Stop Executing the Stored Procedure Now".  The BEGIN and END around it are also not required, but some people might suggest it's better practice to include them any way (But then I'd also include them around the `SET @tmpId = 1` in the ELSE block as well.)